# Removing duplicates and keeping the last entry in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table and I'm trying to remove all the duplicate and keep the
the rows that has the latest datestamp.

Here is the table:

```
email address       orgin_date   new_opt_in_date   datestamp
123@ax.tu            1/1/1900     1/1/1900          3/15/2016
123@ax.tu            1/1/1900     1/1/1900          3/15/2016
iron_man@metrix.com  2/15/2015    3/5/2015          6/6/2017
iron_man@metrix.com  2/15/2015    3/5/2015          7/6/2018
sleep@dort.st        2/15/2015    3/5/201           7/6/2018
sleep@dort.st        2/15/2015    3/5/201           5/6/2018
```

I'm trying to keep only the data that has the recent datestamp and the
output will like this:

```
 email address       orgin_date   new_opt_in_date   datestamp
 123@ax.tu            1/1/1900     1/1/1900          3/15/2016
 iron_man@metrix.com  2/15/2015    3/5/2015          6/6/2017
 sleep@dort.st        2/15/2015    3/5/201           7/6/2018
```

I use this formula:

```
df.drop_duplicates(keep = False)
```

or this one:

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates(subset   
['emailaddress', 'orgin_date', 'new_opt_in_date','datestamp'],keep='first')
print(df1)
```

but nothing works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see from [**the documentation**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) of the method that you can change the `keep` argument to be `"last"`.

In your case, as you only want to consider the values in one of your columns (`datestamp`), you must specify this in the `subset` argument. You had tried passing all column names, which is actually the default behaviour. Now we can use this (along with the correct value for the `keep` argument) to get this:

For example, a dataframe with duplicates:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'datestamp': ['A0', 'A0', 'A2', 'A2'],
                           'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                           'C': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                           'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']}, 
                           index=[0, 1, 2, 3]).T

In [3]: df                                                                      
Out[3]: 
  datestamp   B   C   D
0        A0  B0  B0  D0
1        A0  B1  B1  D1
2        A2  B2  B2  D2
3        A2  B3  B3  D3
```

Now we drop duplicates, passing the correct arguments:

```
In [4]: df.drop_duplicates(subset="datestamp", keep="last")                     
Out[4]: 
  datestamp   B   C   D
1        A0  B1  B1  D1
3        A2  B3  B3  D3
```

By comparing the values across rows 0-to-1 as well as 2-to-3, you can see that only the last values within the `datestamp` column were kept.

Comment: I did try that, but unfortunately it didn't work. I thought using that will only keep the last value, but nothing change or none of the rows were dropped.

Comment: @Learning - please see the edited post, which drop duplicate rows only keeping the most *recent* row, using the `datestamp` column.

Comment: I just used this formula but some reason it is not deleting anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to convert **datestamp** column to datetime format. Using this way I got the required result.

After converting to datetime format, you data will look like this-

```py
>>> df

         email address  orgin_date   new_opt_in_date  datestamp
0            123@ax.tu   1/1/1900        1/1/1900    2016-03-15
1            123@ax.tu   1/1/1900        1/1/1900    2016-03-15
2  iron_man@metrix.com  2/15/2015        3/5/2015    2017-06-06
3  iron_man@metrix.com  2/15/2015        3/5/2015    2018-07-06
4        sleep@dort.st  2/15/2015         3/5/201    2018-07-06
5        sleep@dort.st  2/15/2015         3/5/201    2018-05-06
```

Then sort by both **email address** and **datestamp** (in order) and drop duplicates-

````py
>>> df.sort_values(['email address', 'datestamp']).drop_duplicates(subset = 'email address', keep = 'last')

         email address orgin_date   new_opt_in_date  datestamp
1            123@ax.tu   1/1/1900        1/1/1900    2016-03-15
3  iron_man@metrix.com  2/15/2015        3/5/2015    2018-07-06
4        sleep@dort.st  2/15/2015         3/5/201    2018-07-06 
```
````

Comment: I just tried using this formula but I'm getting an error with email address.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: This is what I got:
----> 1 remixing.sort_values(['Email_Addresss', 'Datestamp']).drop_duplicates(subset = 'Email_Address', keep = 'last')
   1380             values = self.axes[axis].get_level_values(key)._values
   1381         else:
-> 1382             raise KeyError(key)
   1384         # Check for duplicates
KeyError: 'Email_Addresss'

Comment: The column name is "email address" not email addresss.